# How to use Form API and and node_submit to insert taxonomy data

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a content type with a number of text fields and a field linked to a taxonomy vocabulary with about a dozen terms.

I have successfully developed code using the Form API to insert data from my custom form into my node using node_submit for the text fields.  A sniped of the code I use is for the text fields is:

```
$node->field_s_phone[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['phone']; 
$node->field_s_email[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['email'];

node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

I would like to implement a single set of checkboxes of my vocabulary terms on the custom form, then pass the values using node_submit in a similar fashion to the text fields (sort of like):

```
$node->field_catagories[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['catagories'];
```

I would be grateful for any thoughts or insight.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if I completely understood you, this should help.

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach($form_state['values']['catagories'] as $tid) {
      $node->field_catagories[$node->language][$i]['tid'] = $tid;
      $i++;
    }
```